# Expected spy toggleStyle to have been called, when calling function

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am using jasmine testing.

And i have this function:

```
 style: string;
 toggleStyle(style: string, version: string) {
    this.style = `mapbox://styles/mapbox/${style}-${version}`;
  }
```

and template:

```
 <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('outdoors', 'v11')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faMountain" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Outdoors
        </span>
      </div>
```

So I have this unit testing function:

```
 fit('Should mapbox style when user click on icon', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'toggleStyle').and.callThrough();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.map-menu-item')).nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.toggleStyle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

So I call the function: toggleStyle

But I stil get this error:

```
Expected spy toggleStyle to have been called.
```

Of course I googled on this error. But I do a callThrough and I call the function.

So What I have to change?

Thank you

I am using this.style also here:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.style = `mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10`;
    const earthquakes: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection = <any>await import('./amsterdam.geo.json');
    this.earthquakes = {...earthquakes};
  }
```

Here is it used:

```
<mgl-map [style]="style" [zoom]="[9]" [center]="[4.899, 52.372]">
  <mgl-control position="top-left">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start map-menu">
      <span class="map-menu-header">Sensor</span>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleLayer('amsterdam')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faVideo" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>CityHeat
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleLayer('earthquakes')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faWifi" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Wi-Fi
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start map-menu">
      <span class="map-menu-header">Layer</span>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('light', 'v10')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faAdjust" size="sm" flip="horizontal" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Light
        </span>
      </div>     
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('outdoors', 'v11')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faMountain" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Outdoors
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('satellite', 'v9')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faSatellite" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Satellite
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mgl-control>
  
</mgl-map>
```

Comment: I would generally recommend **not** spying on the thing you're supposed to be testing. Test the *behaviour* - where is `this.style` used?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: That looks like where it's first set. Where's it *used* - how would you tell it's been updated?

Comment: Hi, I added the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector selects the first element it matches, so your selector is matching this element:

```
<div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleLayer('amsterdam')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faVideo" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>CityHeat
        </span>
      </div>
```

where the click handler is calling `toggleLayer`.

Change your HTML to be more specific:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start map-menu somethingMoreSpecific">
      <span class="map-menu-header">Layer</span>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('light', 'v10')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faAdjust" size="sm" flip="horizontal" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Light
        </span>
      </div>     
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('outdoors', 'v11')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faMountain" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Outdoors
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="map-menu-item" (click)="toggleStyle('satellite', 'v9')" [state]="[true]" menuItemToggle>
        <span>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faSatellite" size="sm" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>Satellite
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
fit('Should mapbox style when user click on icon', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'toggleStyle').and.callThrough();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.somethingMoreSpecific .map-menu-item')).nativeElement.click(); // change the selector to select the correct div
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.toggleStyle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```